# Регулярное выражение для поиска ссылки

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Нужно находить ссылки следующего типа:

```
https://example.com/section/_cmd/?cmd=assign_workflow_step&arg=true&uid=7777&ptmid=777777&fp=true&pid=77777
```

Цифры `7777`, `777777` и `77777` могут быть различными.

Т.е. нужно выражение для поиска ссылок, которые идентичны приведенной выше, за исключением цифр

Спасибо!

Comment: Покажите примеры ссылок, на которых ваше регулярное выражение не работает. Да само выражение тоже.

Comment: `"https://example.com/section/_cmd/?cmd=assign_workflow_step&arg=true&uid=\d+ptmid=\d+&fp=true&pid=\d+"`

Comment: Ну так замени числа на `\d+`, чтобы выбирались любые.

Answer (score 1):

`\d` означает число. `Один символ`.
`\d+` означает число. `Один символ` или `Много символов`.

`preg_match("/https:\/\/example.com\/section\/_cmd\/\?cmd=assign_workflow_step&arg=true&uid=(\d+)&ptmid=(\d+)&fp=true&pid=(\d+)/", $string, $match);`

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.